# Differentiating $p$ totally wrt $y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE
$$y=2xy'+\frac{1}{y'}$$
if we want to solve it for $x$ ,  we take $x$ in one side
$$2x=\frac{y}{y'}-\frac{1}{y'^2}$$
let's call y' as p , and differentiate wrt $y$
$$\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{y}{p^2}\frac{dp}{dy}+\frac{2}{p^3}\frac{dp}{dy}$$
My problem is not in solving the ODE , I want to know why we considered $p$ ( which is $y'(x)$) as a function of $y$ , (and a function of $y$ only ) ! so we differentiated it totally wrt $y$ ! we wrote $dp/dy$ ...!

Note : the method of solution is in this link http://www.solitaryroad.com/c652.html